# python basic show and return values

Tags: python

I'm using python to input data to my script

then trying to return it back
on demand to show the results

I tried to write it as simple as possible since it's only practicing and trying to get the hang of python

here's how my script looks like

```
#!/usr/python

## imports   #####
##################
import os
import sys

## functions
##################

# GET INSERT DATA
def getdata():
    clientname      = raw_input("   *** Enter Client Name > ")
    phone           = raw_input("   *** Enter Client Phone > ")
    location        = raw_input("   *** Enter Client Location > ")
    email           = raw_input("   *** Enter Client email > ")
    website         = raw_input("   *** Enter Client Website > ")
    return clientname, phone, location, email, website

# VIEW DATA
def showdata():

    print "==================="
    print ""
    print clientname
    print ""
    print phone
    print ""
    print location
    print ""
    print email
    print ""
    print website
    print ""
    print "==================="

# CLEAR
def clear():
    os.system("clear") #linux
    os.system("cls")   #windows

# SHOW INSTRUCTIONS
def welcome():
    clear()
    while True:
        choice          = raw_input(" Select Option > ")
        # INSERT DATA
        if choice == "1":
            getdata()


        # VIEW DATA
        elif choice == "2":
            showdata()

        else:
            print "Invalid Selection.. "
            print "Terminating... "
            #exit()
welcome()
```

what am i doing wrong ? what am i missing?

Comment: What is happening? What did you want to happen?

Comment: i cant show the results when choice is 2

Comment: `getdata()` returns some values but you're not assigning them to any variables when you call it. `showdata()` requires variables but doesn't accept any. Capture the returned variables and pass them as arguments to `showdata()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getdata()` function returns five values. That means when you call it, you can get five values out.

```
clientname, phone, location, email, website = getdata()
```

Then you can pass those into `showdata()` as arguments, if you change the function definition to say:

```
def showdata(clientname, phone, location, email, website):
```

and call it with:

```
showdata(clientname, phone, location, email, website)
```

But of course, that will fail if the user tries to show the data before they have input the data.

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely misusing globals. Please go back and read a good Python tutorial, for example from python.org.

Python is a programming language that allows you to define *functions*, i.e. things that *return* values. You should definitely use that, instead of `global`izing your input. I don't know where you've learned that – every Python ressource that I'd know of will first introduce how to deal properly with functions and their return values before even *mentioning* `global`.

Comment: i was only playing around with that global wondering what kind of error i'd get..
Any advice on what i'm doing wrong with the rest of it ?
much appreciate it

Comment: properly wrapping things in proper functions will solve your issue, see the comments under your question. So that's what you're doing wrong. It really is the misuse of `global`.

Comment: i already removed everything that has to do with global.. any hints on how to *properly wrap things in proper functions* in my case? 
thanks again !

Comment: Hint: *Learn python by reading a good tutorial.* See my answer.

Comment: Now thats a life saver hint Thank you champion !

Comment: Sorry, I can't put it any better; your question is how to fix your programming approach; and my recommendation really is to learn Python step-by-step, and this will fix your code on the way.